# Abstract/Modern Algebra: Homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Find a homomorphism from the quaternion group $Q$ onto $\mathbb{Z}_8^\ast$.

Hint: The kernel must be a normal subgroup of order 2, use the multiplication table of $Q$.
Ans: $\Phi(\pm 1) = 1, \Phi(\pm i) = 3, \Phi(\pm j)= 5, \Phi(\pm k)=7$. The 3,5 and 7 can be permuted.
^ for this question, the answer is given as you can see, I just need to understand it step by step. Thank you

P.S: Multiplication table of $Q$ is:[Multiplication Table of Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg1Sv.jpg)

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand how to approach the problem, or how to start.

Comment: The hint tells you what you have to do. Do you not understand what a homomorphism is?

Comment: I do, I'm just not sure how to apply that to group Q onto Z8